# Can't access child MovieClips in ADDED_TO_STAGE event handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

**problem solved. please see comments. I can't answer my own question due to reputation points.**

I'm trying to develop a simple flash game. I have a symbol and an AS3 class linked to this symbol called Splash (which represents intro screen of Game) and a StartButton symbol. StartButton symbol placed in Splash symbol using Flash IDE given instance name of 'button_start'.

In Splash.as I'm trying to access StartButton's ADDED_TO_STAGE event handler but i got null pointer exception. Here is code:

```
public function Splash() {
    trace("splash const");
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ats);
    super();
}

public function ats(e:Event) {
    trace("splash ats");
    var i:int = 0;
    for (i=0;i<numChildren;i++) {
        if (getChildAt(i).name.search("button")) {
            trace("bulundu");
            buton = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
            buton.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, butonats);
        }
    }
}

function butonats(e:Event) {
    trace("buton ats");         
}
```

Result:

```
splash const
splash ats
bulundu
TypeError: Error #1009: Boş nesne başvuru özelliğine veya yöntemine erişilemiyor.
    at Splash/ats()
```

Doesn't ADDED_TO_STAGE run's when all children ready ? Where is wrong couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Did you googled "Actionscript 3 TypeError: Error #1009" ? I also noticed that you did not declare your `buton` object `var buton:MovieClip;`

Comment: thanks for comment, I declared buton in class level. I also google TypeError 1009. It usually happens when you referance object when it is not ready. They suggest to use ADDED_TO_STAGE event as I do. Couldn't find anything different.

Comment: Did you trace your DisplayList to see what's really available ?

Comment: hm. that is interesting I traced it now and here is the results: buton: null / getChildAt(i): [object Shape]

Comment: You got it I think, Shape is not a MovieClip. `as` operator will return null: [as operator documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#as)

Comment: You can trace your full DisplayList to see exactly what's on.  Do you know how ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's right. I thought my symbol was a MovieClip but It is a shape even It contains a textfield. Don't know why it is a shape. I changed class level variable type to shape and cast it to shape with 'as' operator and problem solved ! thanks for your help. I don't know how to trace full DisplayList by the way   How can I do that? Googled but couldn't find.

Comment: By the way if you can post your comment as answer I can mark question as solved :-) .

Comment: Nice of you, but it's more a debug situation than an answer to a specific question.  Here a post on [How to trace a full Display List beyond the first depth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195452/how-to-trace-a-full-display-list-with-a-recursive-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*button_start* is not an instance of MovieClip, it is a Shape. So making this changes to code solved the problem.

```
var buton:Shape; 
public function Splash() {
   trace("splash const");
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ats);
   super();
}

public function ats(e:Event) {
   trace("splash ats");
   var i:int = 0;
   for (i=0;i<numChildren;i++) {
       if (getChildAt(i).name.search("button")) {
           trace("bulundu");
           buton = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
           buton.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, butonats);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a *button_start*, you mean *button* from this line: `getChildAt(i).name.search("button")`?

Comment: `Shape` is not an `InteractiveObject` so `Shape` will not be appropriate for a button on screen. See the parent class [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) to see the fork.

Comment: button_start is a simple, one frame MovieClip symbol added into Splash symbol with Flash IDE. I don't have enough knowledge about InteractiveObject object or DisplayObject but I think for a simple one frame Shape would be enough.