# How to trace a full Display List with a recursive function?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to see all instances on the Display List of a specific [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html). How to do it with a recursive function to see beyond the first depth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple recursive function to trace a Display List. In a MovieClip, this line : `traceDisplayL(this, 2);` can output:

```
 root1 MainMe
     Alone Symbol1
         Shape
     BigOne Symbol2
         Shape
         InBigOne Symbol3
```

The import section:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.display.MovieClip; 
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
```

The `traceDisplayL` function: (don't use the `currentDepth` parameter, leave it as is)

```
    public function traceDisplayL(displayObject:DisplayObject, maxDepth:int = 20, levelSpace:String = " ", currentDepth:int = 0) {

        var className:String = String(getQualifiedClassName(displayObject));
        var indexOfString:int = className.lastIndexOf("::");
        className = (indexOfString < 0) ? className : className.slice(indexOfString + 2);

        var displayName:String =  String((displayObject.name.substr(0, 8) == "instance") ? "" : displayObject.name + " ");

        trace(levelSpace + displayName + className);   

        if (displayObject is DisplayObjectContainer && currentDepth < maxDepth) {       
            for (var i:int = 0; i < DisplayObjectContainer(displayObject).numChildren; i++) {
                traceDisplayL(DisplayObjectContainer(displayObject).getChildAt(i), maxDepth, levelSpace + "    ", currentDepth + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

And a more elaborate one `traceDisplayList` (using two other functions). You will see text on the side if the object is a `TextField`, and if you want to:

- only "instance" object (those who have a name);
- data related to object (.x, .y, .width, .height);
- parent object name, after the object name;

You can also limit the maximum depth, and/or skip all objects of a specific Class (if you don't want to see any `Shape` or Whatever in your trace).

```
    public static function traceDisplayList(displayObject:DisplayObject, instanceOnly:Boolean = false, withData:Boolean = false, withParent:Boolean = false, maxDepth:int = 100, skipClass:Class = null, levelSpace:String = " ", currentDepth:int = 0, parent:String = ""):void 
    {
        if (skipClass != null) { if (displayObject is skipClass) { return; } }

        var displayName:String = displayObjectCleanName(displayObject);
        displayName += (displayName != "") ? " " : "";
        if (instanceOnly && displayName == "") { return; }

        var className:String = getCleanClassName(displayObject);

        var text:String = (className == "TextField") ? String(" \"" + TextField(displayObject).text) + "\"" : ""

        var objectName:String = displayName + className + text;

        var dataString:String = (withData) ? String(" [x:" + displayObject.x + " y:" + displayObject.y + " width:" + displayObject.width + " height:" + displayObject.height + "]") : "";

        var parentName:String = (withParent && parent != "") ? String(" (" +  parent + ")") : "";   

        var levelStr:String = (withParent) ? String(currentDepth + " ") : "";

        trace(levelStr + levelSpace + objectName + dataString + parentName);

        if (displayObject is DisplayObjectContainer && currentDepth < maxDepth)
        {       
            for (var i:int = 0; i < DisplayObjectContainer(displayObject).numChildren; i++)
            {
                traceDisplayList(DisplayObjectContainer(displayObject).getChildAt(i), instanceOnly, withData, withParent, maxDepth, skipClass, levelSpace + "    ", currentDepth + 1, objectName);
            }
        }
    }   

    public static function getCleanClassName(obj:*):String 
    {
        var className:String = String(getQualifiedClassName(obj));
        var indexOfString:int = className.lastIndexOf("::");
        className = (indexOfString < 0) ? className : className.slice(indexOfString + 2);
        return className;           
    }

    public static function displayObjectCleanName(displayObject:DisplayObject):String
    {
        return String((displayObject.name.substr(0, 8) == "instance") ? "" : displayObject.name);
    }
```

Comment: I would also suggest checking out FlexSpy https://code.google.com/p/fxspy/ or if you're in pure AS3 http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest code that you can recursively see all the parents of a `DisplayObject`
going to top from bottom. Add `numChildren` tweak and you can see all other children of the parent too.

```
function traceD(mc:DisplayObject) {
   trace(mc);
   if(mc.parent!=null) traceD(mc.parent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't get this concept of finding maximum items recursively

```
public static int Get-Max(int[] List, int count)

{ int max=-500000;
   if(count<=0)
    return -1;

   else
    {
    if(List[x]>max)
    max=List[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it would seem that you don't